# Flask If Statement - Range for list index

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, range

customer_data.json (loaded as customer_data)

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "username": "anonymous",
      "id": "1234",
      "password": "12341234",
      "email": "1234@gmail.com",
      "status": false,
      "books": [
        "Things Fall Apart",
        "Fairy Tales",
        "Divine Comedy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example post in new_catalog.json. (loaded as posts)

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "author": "Chinua Achebe",
      "country": "Nigeria",
      "language": "English",
      "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
      "pages": 209,
      "title": "Things Fall Apart",
      "year": 1958,
      "hold": false
    }
}
```

Necessary code in Flask_practice.py

```
    for customer in customer_data['customers']:
        if len(customer['books']) > 0:
            for book in customer['books']:
                holds.append(book)
    
    for post in posts['books']:
        if post['title'] == holds[range(len(holds))]:
            matching_posts['books'].append(post)
```

`holds[range(len(holds))]` doesn't work.

I am trying to go through each of the books in `holds` using `holds[0], holds[1]` etc and test to see if the `title` is equal to a book title in `new_catalog.json`.

I'm still new to Flask, Stack Overflow and coding in general so there may be a really simple solution to this problem.

Comment: What did you expect `holds[range(len(holds))]` to do? `holds` is presumably a list, and lists can only be indexed by _integers_, but `range(len(holds))` is _not_ an integer, so the code fails.

Comment: I realize it doesn't work but I was trying to loop through each of the items in holds using ```holds[1], holds[2]``` etc and compare it to ```post['title']```

Comment: `if any(post["title"] == h for h in holds):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to go through each of the books in `holds` using `holds[0]`, `holds[1]` etc and test to see if the title is equal to a book title

Translated almost literally to Python:

```
# For each post...
for post in posts['books']:
    # ...go through each of the books in `holds`...
    for hold in holds:
        # ...and see if the title is equal to a book title
        if post['title'] == hold:
            matching_posts['books'].append(post)
```

Or, if you don't want to `append(post)` *for each item in `holds`*:

```
for post in posts['books']:
    if post['title'] in holds:
        matching_posts['books'].append(post)
```